# Rails 3: Why am I getting EOFError with DELETE request and no form body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, postman

I created the following route in Rails 3:

```
delete '/api/v1/foo/groups/:group_id', to: 'Manager#delete_group', constraints: { group_id: /\d+/ }
```

I am using Postman to send a DELETE request to that route without a form body.
Why am I getting the following error?

```
EOFError in ManagerController#delete_group
bad content body
```

When I add dummy values to the form body then I don't get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. The tool Postman was at fault (if we were talking about usability here). I selected the "form-data" option and deleted the form data I had there so that I had no data to post. Then when Postman sends the request it still creates a multipart/form-data boundary in the body containing no data AND no matching boundary. By fiddling with Postman (selecting x-www-form-urlencoded, raw or binary) I was able to bypass this behaviour and the DELETE requests works without error. I had to step into Rails source to figure this out (shudder!!!).

Comment: Thanks Man! Helped me a lot. 
In my case, it wasn't the specific header you pointed out, but the: Content-Type:multipart/form-data; that came without content.
But indeed, the error message is not elightening. Put some hours into this.